# In Unity, what does the camera script's "Behaviour missing" error mean?

Tags: unity, camera, control

I started in Unity few days ago and made a cube with a tank control style. Now I'd like to create controls similar to 3D fighting games ([Gunz](http://store.steampowered.com/app/242720/), [Blade Symphony](http://www.blade-symphony.com/), …): Control body direction with the mouse and walk with WASD.

However, the Camera is giving me a error called "Behaviour missing" each time I try, with all the cameras scripts I saw. I think that is a error with tagging the character movement in the camera, but I don't know how to do that.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Does the error mention anything else? Why is that first bit about controls relevant when the issue you're having is with the camera? (Does it only happen when you try to make it move with the mouse?)

Answer (score 2):

It's not wrong with the camera or with the content of any script you might have. This error occurs when you have a script attached to a gameobject and you deleted, moved or renamed it outside of unity. Unity can't find the related script for the MonoBehaviour component.

If you want to rename or move a script do it always in Unity. To solve your error, just find the component that references this missing script and drag the script that you might have moved onto the component.